# Passing data from one form to another, where there is an intermediate form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a small application , and I am thinking to pass a textbox value from another form to another. I know how to pass data directly where there are two forms, but in my case I have also an intermediate form ( where user can choose cash or credit card, and depend on the choice, then is opened the form(frm_cash or frm_credit). After I click the button OK one the form( ( frm_cash or frm_credit ))  I want the textbox from ( frm_cash or frm_credit ) to be displayed into frm1 textbox. If someone could help me about this one?

Comment: Why not have a class which encapsulates this shared data and have this class passed to each form - similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280482/dynamically-edit-the-data-between-two-forms-in-winforms-c-sharp/62280915#62280915

Comment: As long as you keep a reference to each form you can pass values around by assigning or reading their properties. For reference types, it will all point to the same data (in memory) and no copies or duplicates will be created.

Comment: Please show _how_ you pass data between two forms, as there are multiple ways of doing so and if you want an answer that is compatible with your existing code you need to provide more details in your question. Use the [edit] button.

Comment: I didn't pass the data between forms, where did you see that I passed. I asked for help how to pass data

Comment: Also thank You for down voting

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this selection is only ever made ONCE at a time (you wouldn't have multiple cash/credit dialogs open at the same time).  If this is the case, you could just use a `static` member of a class to store the value.  The static member can be accessed from anywhere using the class name followed by the static member name.  Here's a simple class as an example:

```
public class PurchaseType
{

    public static PurchaseTypeOptions SelectedType;

    public enum PurchaseTypeOptions
    {
        Cash,
        Credit
    }

}
```

You could store the selection using code like this:

```
PurchaseType.SelectedType = PurchaseType.PurchaseTypeOptions.Credit;
```

Then from somewhere else you could access it with something like:

```
switch(PurchaseType.SelectedType)
{
    case PurchaseType.PurchaseTypeOptions.Cash:
        // ... do something for Cash ...
        break;

    case PurchaseType.PurchaseTypeOptions.Credit:
        // ... do something for Credit ...
        break;
}
```

Comment: I don't need to store the type of transaction. But based on the transaction selected, different form are opened. And on this form I make the transacation. Now what I need Is when the form CASH is opened there I put details( paid and change) and when clicking ok, these details should displayed on main form(txtpayment) or when I click CREDIT , the credit form is opened and there I choose the bank with which I made the payment with credit card, and after clicking ok the information should be displayed back on the main form (txtpayment)

Comment: The details are irrelevant.  You asked how to transfer data between forms.  This example shows you one way using STATIC fields.  You could add more than one static field if you need to communicate more than one thing.  The key detail here is that communication using static fields is only appropriate when you don't need to communicate multiple sets of data between specific forms (requiring you to pass specific instances around).  This approach could be modified to suit your needs described above; study it.

Answer (score 0):

> After I click the button OK one the form( ( frm_cash or frm_credit ))
>   I want the textbox from ( frm_cash or frm_credit ) to be displayed
>   into frm1 textbox.

So presumably, in frm1, you are creating an instance of frm_cash or frm_credit and displaying it.  After those forms are closed (by clicking OK) you want to update frm1 with some information from one of those forms.

This is typically done by displaying the form (frm_cash/frm_credit) with [ShowDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1).  This causes execution in frm1 to STOP until the child form is dismissed.  Once dismissed, you can use the instance variable of the child form to retrieve information from it.

In the child form, you dismiss the dialog (subsequently returning execution to the parent form) by setting [DialogResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Form_DialogResult).  So in the child form you'd have code like this:

```
// ... code in either frm_cash or frm_credit ...
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do some validation...and if everything is okay, set DialogResult
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}

private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this gets set automatically if the user clicks the X in the top right
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel; 
}
```

Back in frm1, you'd use code like this to display the form and take action based on DialogResult:

```
// ... code in frm1 ...
private void btnCredit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmCredit credit = new frmCredit();
    if (credit.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // code STOPS here until "credit" is dismissed
    {
        // we only get in here if "OK" was returned
        this.textBox1.Text = credit.XXX; // retrieve something from "credit"
    }
}
```

Obviously, in frm_cash and frm_credit, you need to create public properties to expose the details so they can be accessed from frm1, as in my `credit.XXX` example.

Comment: Again you misunderstood. The form credit isn't opened directly like you mention on your answer. But the mediate form is opened( form_payment) where you choose the form you want.  frmCredit credit = new frmCredit();
    if (credit.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // code STOPS here until "credit" is dismissed
    {
        // we only get in here if "OK" was returned
        this.textBox1.Text = credit.XXX; // retrieve something from "credit"
    }   You can't wait directly from form credit, cause we don't know which form will open.

Comment: You already stated that you know "how to pass data directly where there are two forms".  So now you have three forms and need to use TRANSITIVE property like in Math: A=B and B=C, then A=C.  So pass from C to B, then B to A.  Since you haven't shown any code, we don't know how you are displaying the forms and passing data...but this technique could definitely be used to achieve this goal.  A shows B with ShowDialog.  B shows C or D with ShowDialog.  Then grab the info daisy chain it along...

Comment: not three but four forms, again you are not reading correctly the question. 1. Main for where you click to open 2 the Intermediate where you can choose 3 the cash form or 4 the credit form. Read the question before, and understand what is being asked

Comment: Seriously? From your 2nd form, you open EITHER one or the other; so effectively only 3 forms.  You don't have four forms open at the same time where you are communicating from all of them.  So your effective problem only has THREE forms and you can apply this approach to your situation.  You still haven't posted any relevant code to illuminate all these details you keep talking about.  If you leave your question generic, then you should only expect generic answers.  Notice you now have -2 on your question?  Fix it...